# XmlSerializer + Abstract class + Derived classes = Useless namespaces

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, xml-namespaces

My first question on **SO** :,) and it's about **XmlSerializer** and namespace issue.

I know that there's already a lot of subject on how to remove the default Xml namespace from the root element of the Xml file and it's not the subject.

My question is how to remove it from child nodes when you're using derived classes ?

I've created my own serializer that can take custom namespaces or simply ignore them, and it's working well for the root element.

But when I use an abstract class to list some derived classes inside a **List** the serialization insert 2 attributes inside each derived classes' nodes.

Like this :

```
<root>
  <elements>
    <element p3:type="XmlDerivedClass" xmlns:p3="{schema_url}" >
    </element>
  </elements>
</root>
```

As for my classes :

```
// Root element
[XmlRoot("root", Namespace="")]
public class XmlRootElement
{
    List<XmlBaseClass> _Elements;
}    

// Base class
[XmlInclude(typeof(XmlDerivedClass))] // Mandatory, prevents serialization errors
[XmlRoot(Namespace="")]
public abstract class XmlBaseClass

// Derived class
[XmlRoot("element", Namespace="")]
public class XmlDerivedClass : XmlBaseClass
```

I tried some common solutions :

- Using the Namespace="" attribute
- Implementing the **XmlNamespaceDeclarations** property (with the right empty Namespace)
- Moving the **XmlRoot()** from base clase to derived one
- Changing **XmlRoot()** to **XmlElement()**

I'll try to add the XmlInclude tag on the **List** to see if it changes something.

So far, nothing worked to remove those damn namespaces...

If anyone has a solution for this, I'll be glad to try it.

**[EDIT 21/02/2014]**
Well, it seems that I'm the only one facing this issue. I'll use a simple **string.Replace** to remove the useless XML but that's quite dirty.

---

*PS : For the context, the tags aren't an issue for the parser on the other end BUT they're not needed so I'm looking for a way to remove them.*

*PS2 : Sorry for the any spelling mistakes, English isn't my native language.*

Comment: I tried to add the **[XmlArrayItem("element", Type=typeof(XmlDerivedClass))]** but it solved the problem for only one derived class.

With multiple derived classes with the same node name, it doesn't work with this system.

Comment: Have you found any solution for this? I have the exact same problem.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure whether this is a solution which satisfies your needs because it's not really nice but it works and it doesn't seem too dirty.

```
public abstract class Abs
{
    public int Data { get; set; }
}


public class A : Abs{}

public class B : Abs{}

[Serializable]
[XmlRoot(elementName: "name")]
public class Ser
{
    [XmlElement(elementName: "A")]
    public List<A> AList { get; set; }

    [XmlElement(elementName: "B")]
    public List<B> BList { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public List<Abs> AbsList {
        get
        {
            var list = new List<Abs>(AList.ConvertAll(x=>(Abs)x));
            list.AddRange(BList.ConvertAll(x=>(Abs)x));
            return list;
        }
    }
}
```

Instead of XmlInclude you can create a List with derived-class objects and afterwards add them together or maybe cache them within a private member. 
Please notice again this is still far from ideal but it works for me so i wanted to share it.

Comment: Anyhow if you use an array you can use the **XmlElement** and **XmlArrayItem** attributes to do the job for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you add `[XmlType]`, you can give the serializer the information about the type, such as the namespace it belongs to:

```
// Base class
[XmlInclude(typeof(XmlDerivedClass))] // Mandatory, prevents serialization errors
[XmlType(Namespace="")]
public abstract class XmlBaseClass

// Derived class
[XmlType("element", Namespace="")]
public class XmlDerivedClass : XmlBaseClass
```

Comment: Thanks for this, I'll give it a try as soon as possible.

Comment: Now I'm getting a funny results `<element p3:type="element"... >`. I'll try to play with the **XmlTypeAttribute** to see if I can get something better.